# pass counter value from a for each to another

Tags: xml, xslt

So here is my XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<catalog>
  <cd>
    <title>Empire Burlesque</title>
    <artist>Bob Dylan</artist>
    <country>USA</country>
  </cd>
  <cb>
   <title>Car</title>
    <speed>420</speed>
    <hp>1200</hp>
   </cb> 
 <cb>
   <title>something</title>
    <speed>blabla</speed>
    <hp>31415</hp>
   </cb> 
</catalog>
```

here is my XSLT containing 2 for each loops

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:template match="/">

    <xsl:for-each select="catalog/cd">
 <xsl:number value="position()" format="1. "/>
    <xsl:value-of select="title"/>
      <br/>
    </xsl:for-each>

   <xsl:for-each select="catalog/cb">
 <xsl:number value="position()" format="1. "/>
    <xsl:value-of select="hp"/>
      <br/>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

and here is my output

1 Empire Burlesque
1 1200

2 31415

The question is: Am i able somehow to pass the counter value from the first for-each to the second and use it as an input to position?So My output will be: (1. Empire Burlesque
2. 1200
3. 31415)  I thought some thing as Position()+Variable but it didn't bring something.

Comment: what about having one template, that matches catalog/cd OR catalog/cb ?

Answer (score 1):

Here's one way you could look at it:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:variable name="count-cd" select="count(catalog/cd)" />

    <xsl:for-each select="catalog/cd">
        <xsl:number value="position()" format="1. "/>
        <xsl:value-of select="title"/>
        <br/>
    </xsl:for-each>

    <xsl:for-each select="catalog/cb">
        <xsl:number value="$count-cd + position()" format="1. "/>
        <xsl:value-of select="hp"/>
        <br/>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Two features of this solution: 1. Uses `<xsl:for-each>`  2. Uses a variable to calculate the starting numbering value for the processing of the `cb` elements. Both are unnecessary, and no. 1 is considered bad style.

Comment: For the less experienced reader: there is absolutely nothing wrong or "bad style" in using `<xsl:for-each>`; it is an integral part of the XSLT language. Nor is there anything wrong with using a variable the way it is used here - I would certainly prefer it to sorting.

Comment: Yes, and if there were 30 differently named children of `catalog` you would use 30 different variables... Good luck with that

Comment: @DimitreNovatchev If the question were different, my answer could well be different too. I am not here to engage in speculations or imaginary scenarios.

Comment: Questions at SO are minimal and simplified on purpose. The real-world scenarios are often magnified. So, these are not "imaginary scenarios". To put it in another way: at least a little imagination is a great helper in solving problems.

Answer (score 1):

tested, clean solution

```
    <xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
                xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

    <!--without this, xsl number will not produce numbers 1,2,3 but 2,4,6.
   We need to stop parsing unwanted nodes -->
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <!--match either catalog/cd or catalog/cb -->
    <xsl:template match="catalog/cd|catalog/cb">
        <xsl:number value="position()" format="1. "/>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
        <xsl:text>&#xa;</xsl:text>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="catalog/cd/title">
        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="catalog/cb/hp">
        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
    </xsl:template>

    <!--we need to stop processing text for all other nodes -->
    <xsl:template match="text()"/>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Note: in the output cd and cb nodes are presented in same order as in the source document.

This solution is (for me) more idiomatic usage of XSLT. No need to use for-each.
Each detail has short, specific template rather than one long template for everything.

Answer (score 1):

> I like the solution by **Bartosz Bilicki**, but the problem is to output
>   all `cd` data first and only then -- all `cb` data. In the current XML document the `<cd>`s just *happen* to precede all `<cb>`s -- in general these could be mixed.
>   **No passing of starting numbering value . . .**

**Here is a a short/simple solution that does exactly that without** `<xsl:for-each>` and **uses no parameters or variables to pass the starting numbering value, and doesn't suppose any specific ordering of the `cd` or `cb` elements**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output method="text"/>

  <xsl:template match="/*">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="*">
     <xsl:sort select="string-length(substring-before('cdcb', name()))"/>
    </xsl:apply-templates>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="cd|cb">
    <xsl:number value="position()" format="1. "/>
    <xsl:value-of select="hp | self::cd/title"/>
    <xsl:text>&#xa;</xsl:text>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**When this transformation is applied on the provided XML document**:

```
<catalog>
    <cd>
        <title>Empire Burlesque</title>
        <artist>Bob Dylan</artist>
        <country>USA</country>
    </cd>
    <cb>
        <title>Car</title>
        <speed>420</speed>
        <hp>1200</hp>
    </cb>
    <cb>
        <title>something</title>
        <speed>blabla</speed>
        <hp>31415</hp>
    </cb>
</catalog>
```

**the wanted, correct result is produced**:

```
1. Empire Burlesque
2. 1200
3. 31415
```

Comment: smart using of variable to maintain continous numbering. I see no way doing this without variables (in plain XSLT 1.0, without extensions).

Comment: @BartoszBilicki, I updated the solution. In fact, this numbering is possible without the use of any xsl:param or xsl:variable !

Comment: smart! I have never used xslt:sort. I tried to achieve that solution without params, using apply-template or modes, but I failed to maintain continous numbering.

Comment: @BartoszBilicki There is no advantage in avoiding params/variables. On the contrary.

Comment: @BartoszBilicki, I want to thank you for asking if it were possible to avoid calculating counts and passing them as parameters -- this led to a much better solution. Unnecessary variables / params result in unnecessarily-complicated code, gradually leading to a mess that is difficult to understand and maintain.